# htaccess rewrite with key/value pairs

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know somehow you can have a url such as `foo.com/me/data/key1/val1/key2/val2` with a random amount of key/value pairs in it. I assume it is a recursive rule needed to accomplish this, but so far I have:

```
RewriteRule ^(data)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ /$1/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(data)/(/[^/]+|[^/]+/|/?)$ /datahandler.php [L,QSA]
```

But this isn't working. I get a 404 error. I need the `data` part of the url to distinguish it from any other requests.

This is the current structure of the site:

```
Site Root
- .htaccess (1)
- index.php
- /Me
- - .htaccess(2)
- - index.php
- - /Scripts
- - - handler.php
```

The content of the htaccess files:

```
.htaccess (1)
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^Me/?(.*)$ /Me/$1 [NC,L]

.htaccess (2)
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(data)(?:Scripts\/handler\.php)?/([^/]+)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ /$1Scripts/handler.php/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in just a single rule. Place this in your `/me/.htaccess` folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Me/

RewriteRule ^(data|Scripts/handler\.php)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ Scripts/handler.php/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't really worked, I have edited my question with a bit more detail if you could possibly work from that?

Comment: Try edited answer now, I believe your folder is `/me/` not `/Me/`

Comment: It is `/Me/`, but could you explain what the `RewriteBase` does?

Comment: Also may I know what is the actual internal URL you want after all the rewrites?

Comment: It returns a 404 error, if it's not possible I can work around it. I would be looking for a url `foo.com/me/data/editsetting/news/sid/123/`

Comment: No that is not your actual internal URL. It will be something with query string with `?key1=val1&key2=val2`

Comment: Sorry, the url would be `foo.com/Me/Scripts/handler.php?editsettings=news&sid=123`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(data)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(?:/(.+)|)$ /$1/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(data)/?$ /datahandler.php [L]
```

The first rule you got right, but the second rule has too many slashes.